# JK Flip-Flop as a frequency divider by 3 with a Duty cycle of 50%

Tags: flipflop

I've been doing a little research into this but I cannot find anywhere on how to divide a frequency 3 by 3 using JK flip flops, only this:

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-divideby3.html

But it is a D Flipflop.

I know how to divide by 2, 4, 8..etc

But how do I go about building a circuit to divide by 3?

Comment: you can use a 3 bit ring counter but it won't give 50% duty cycle

Comment: I think you will need to clock at least one FF on the positive edge, and one FF on the negative edge.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to divide by an odd number and get a 50% duty cycle output is to use both edges of the clock signal, and this requires that the clock itself have a 50% duty cycle as well.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOxDE4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's no advantage to using J-K flip-flops for this; the circuit is exactly the same, with the `J` inputs connected where the `D` inputs are, and the `K` inputs tied high.

Comment: Your statement about how to connect a J-K flip-flop as a D flip-flop is not correct.  For example, see  http://www.circuitstoday.com/flip-flop-conversion#JKtoD .  I'll delete this comment after you have corrected your answer.

Comment: Thanks but I need to know how to do this with JK flipflops as I havn't learned about D Flipflops yet, Is it not possible to do this or something? everywhere I look on the internet it's done by D Flipflops

Comment: @DwayneReid: I never said, nor intended to imply, that the connection I described was a general way to replace a D flip-flop with a J-K flip-flop. I just described a connection that works *for this circuit only*.

Comment: @Modrisco: That's because nobody designs with J-K flip-flops any more. It's an obsolete technology of only academic interest at this point in time. All substantial new logic design is done with HDLs (hardware description languages), which are all D flip-flop based.

Comment: That's fine, my question is acdemically related though, I've been researching this for 2 days with no sucess, if you can show me how to build it I'd be grateful, I can figure it out how it works from there then.

Comment: Which part of the last part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: Well you showed me clearly how it's done with D flip-flops, are you saying I just replace the Ds with Js? and that will work?

Comment: The purpose of school is to learn, and to exert some effort to understand. Even though you have not yet learned about D flip-flops, you can read about them on the internet, try to understand how the above works, and then see if you can make it work for the JK flip-flop. The key point is NOT the type of flip-flop. They key point is that you need to invert the clock. I very strongly suggest you draw a timing diagram  showing the clock, and the  desired output, and study it.

Comment: Thanks for explantion of how school works, had no idea.